# Cannot add SSH key to MaaS

Tags: ssh, maas

- I have install Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0-24-generic.
- As MaaS I have generate SSH keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
- I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> for no passphrase
- I have typed `more ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to get the key
- I have copied it to MaaS, using copy/paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and got an error in the MaaS GUI: "invalid key"

Comment: how does the key look like? Public part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I realized there were newlines introduced when I cut-pasted the key. After removing the newlines the key upload worked.